# What does the Spare Parts mod do?

Tags: warframe

In warframe there is a mod for sentinels (I can't remember whether it was rare or uncommon, or whether I got it from nightmare mode or not) called "spare parts", and its description goes along the lines of "+X drop rate" (I don't remember what number it is, and it increases when it is upgraded). I have seen people requesting that their team have fully upgraded spare parts, but I don't understand exactly what drop rate means. (I use a deth cube, if it matters)

Does it increase the chance of enemies killed by the modded sentinel dropping mods/materials at all, does it increase the chance of those enemies to drop rarer mods and materials, or does it increase the rate/rarity of drops from the sentinel when *it* is destroyed? I wasn't aware that sentinels did drop pickups when they broke, but because the mod is named "spare parts", it makes me think that the sentinel itself will have more drops, plus it is applied to the sentinel itself, not whatever weapon it uses.

Also, does the mod affect your own weapons too, meaning that any kills you get with your sword/pistol/rifle also have increased drops? I haven't seen any drop rate mods for any other gear, so it would make sense to make the only drop rate modifier be universal. And if so, does the effect also apply to your entire team, and if a teammate's sentinel also has the mod, will it stack (ex: you have +5 drop rate + friend has +2.5 drop rate = team has +7.5 drop rate)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Spare Parts grants a chance for Sentinels to drop rare resources upon destruction.](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Spare_Parts)

From the wiki:

- A Sentinel will not drop a resource if queued for a Regen.
- A Sentinel destroyed in PvP will not drop a resource.
- A Sentinel will not drop a resource more than once per mission if Revives are used by the player.